# I am learning how to do the unit tests for the controllers and i don't know how to do it correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, mocking

I'm learning how to test controllers and I still don't understand some things. I've watched some tutorials and I read some pages to learn but I don't understand 100%. I tried to do it but I don't think it's correct. I'm using Spring Boot and Mock.

This is my controller class:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

@Autowired
private ShopService shopService;

@Autowired
private GameService gameService;

@GetMapping(value = "/userProfile")
public String userProfile(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
    User us = null;
    if (principal instanceof User) {
        us = (User) principal;
    }
    model.addAttribute("user", us);
    model.addAttribute("teamsCreated", this.userService.teamsCreated(us));
    model.addAttribute("teamshejoined", this.userService.teamsHeJoined(us));
    model.addAttribute("gamesheplays", this.gameService.findGamesHePlays(us.getId()));
    model.addAttribute("groupgamesheplays", this.gameService.findGroupHePlays(us));
    model.addAttribute("prizehewon", this.gameService.getPrizeHeWon(us));

    return "user/profile";
}
```

This is my test class:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

@MockBean
private ShopService shopService; 

@MockBean 
private UserRepository userRepository;

@MockBean
private DataUserRepository dataUserRepository;

private User user;
private DataUser dataUser;
private Team team;
private Set<User> people;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    
    user = new User();
    user.setId(12L);
    user.setUsername("usertest");
    user.setPassword("Pass1234");
    dataUser.setId(915495L);
    dataUser.setMoney(1);
    dataUser.setUser(user);
    user.setDataUser(dataUser);
    
    people = new HashSet<>();
    people.add(user);
    
    team = new Team();
    team.setId(2L);
    team.setName("team1");
    team.setCreator(user);
    team.setPeople(people);
    team.setCreationDate(Date.from(Instant.now()));
}

    @WithMockUser(value = "spring")
@Test
void testProcessCreationUser() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(post("/userProfile")
            .with(csrf())
            .param("username", "usertest")
            .param("password", "Pass1234")
            .param("id", "49L")
            .param("dataUser", ?????? )) // the ?? is because I dont know how to add a dataUser type, I only know Strings
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("users/createClienteForm"));
    
}
```

I tried doing it seeing previous methods some people made and with what I read before in notes I took, but i don't really understand so if you could tell me if that's correct or what is wrong and I could do better and I'd appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Controllers have more of an integration test feel to me, not unit test.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're trying to mock a `@GetMapping` as a `post()` and it will not work.

Second, it seems that your resource does not need any parameter as it only gathers information about the user that is logged in your system, am I correct?

So, your test should look like:

```java
@WithMockUser(value = "spring")
@Test
void testProcessCreationUser() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(get("/userProfile")
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("users/createClienteForm"));
    
}
```

You should review to which page your user will be redirected at the end, as
`users/createClienteForm` doesn't seem to be the corrected one in your mock.

Also, always choose a name for your test that correctly explains what your test is doing/verifying. I think `testShowUserProfile` should be fine in your case.

Comment: @EricSchaefer, be aware that this test is generally considered as an integration test, not unit test. The terminology is still not 100% aligned, but at least for me if it boots spring context during the test, it is an integration test. A pure mock test and no spring dependencies would be a unit test